# How to fix Fullscreen focus error in Unity?

Tags: unity, 12.10

Recently, I've been experiencing an error with programs that have a fullscreen mode with low resolution (80xx600 and below) in Unity. The problem isn't valid in gnomeshell. Whenever I launch an application, unity would enlarge the screen more than it should be and would only show me the upper left corner of the screen (I only see a magnified quarter of the screen). At first I thought that it was an issue related to wine but I later found out that native applications (such as world of goo) are affected as well. Apps that taken on the full screen but have a larger resolution don't face such an issue. Is it possible to get this fixed manually? Or do I have to wait for updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes same case for me to play the old Age of Empires in wine in 800x600 or 1024x768 resolutions while my screen is natively in 1280x1024.
Solution : switch to the target resolution *before* launching the app so that it does not need to switch to the lower resolution itself:

```
xrandr -s 1024x768; wine etc.;xrandr -s 1280x1024
```